# Excel - choosing numbers from bigger data set

Tags: excel

I have a question about excel (hopefully on the right forum)

I have a data of 100 numbers in excel and I want to randomly choose 30 numbers with the fact that the same number is not chosen again (so by removing the number that was already selected)

And I come across by not knowing on how to do that?
I tried with RANDBETWEEN(1;100) and copying it 30 times but it is/can repeat the same number.

Could you please offer me assistance on how to do that?
Thank you.
..............

Is there a way to do this with worksheat formulas instead of using VBA -that some other forun questions suggest?

.......

Comment: Try this link- https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2484-excel-random-number-no-duplicates-no-repeat.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is some Excel VBA Code which should do the trick

```
 Sub RandomUniquiNumber()

      Dim NumberArray As Variant
      ReDim NumberArray(100)

      Dim NumberArrayPosition As Long

      For NumberArrayPosition = 1 To 100

           NumberArray(NumberArrayPosition) = NumberArrayPosition

      Next NumberArrayPosition

      Dim Result As Variant
      ReDim Result(30)
      Dim ResultPositionNumber As Long
      Dim ResultString As String
      Dim RandomNumber As String
      Dim InStrResult As Long

      ResultString = ""

      For ResultPositionNumber = 1 To 30

           RandomNumber = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 100)
           InStrResult = InStr(1, ResultString, RandomNumber)
           If InStrResult = 0 Then

                ResultString = ResultString & " " & RandomNumber

           Else

                Do While InStrResult > 1

                      RandomNumber = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 100)
                      InStrResult = InStr(1, ResultString, RandomNumber)

                 Loop

                ResultString = ResultString & " " & RandomNumber

           End If

           'Result in an Array
           Result(ResultPositionNumber) = RandomNumber


      Next ResultPositionNumber

      'If you want the result as an Array Use Result(ResultPositionNumber)
      'If you want the result as an Array Use ResultString


 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this variation.

In column A put in the 100 numbers in order.
For each number in column A, put =RAND() in column B.

Then sort the array using column B.

Pick off the top 30 numbers in column A.